# Gradle not sync compile dependency of Pubnative library

Tags: android

When Gradle sync it sync some of file but some file are not sync

```
Error:(36, 17) Failed to resolve: org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2
Error:(35, 17) Failed to resolve: org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2
Error:(33, 17) Failed to resolve: org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+
Error:(37, 17) Failed to resolve: org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.2
Error:(31, 17) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
Error:(30, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
These file gradle not sync and give it error. When i clean project then it give this type of error as given below
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':library:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find org.droidparts:droidparts:2.6.7.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/droidparts/droidparts/2.6.7/droidparts-2.6.7.pom
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/droidparts/droidparts/2.6.7/droidparts-2.6.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/droidparts/droidparts/2.6.7/droidparts-2.6.7.pom
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/droidparts/droidparts/2.6.7/droidparts-2.6.7.jar
Required by:
CashbackKorting:library:unspecified
> Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom
file:/C:/Users/Fawad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar
Required by:
CashbackKorting:library:unspecified
```

Please give appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're having a wrong version of cache, if you could invalidate and restart android studio, the caches will get empty and forced to download those libraries again.

Android studio > File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...